# Sending Triggered emails in SFMC using cloud connector

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, triggered-send

I need to trigger emails from SFMC. Input is given by user through a form on website. The record will be updated in SFDC and then in SFMC email will be triggered when record is updated in a Data extension.

I have created triggered send email and TriggeredSend DE in SFMC. I have marketing cloud connector installed and setup done. What is the process that is to be followed in this?

Comment: If my answer helped, please mark it as accepted so others can easily see this has been solved. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set up the trigger in SFDC, so the email is triggered as soon as a record fulfills the desired criteria:

1. From the Sales or Service Cloud, click the Marketing Cloud tab
2. Click Triggered Sends
3. Click New
4. Complete the form/wizard

Further information on all the options and fields can be found in the [documentation article "Create a Triggered Send"](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_connector_v5/sending_emails/triggered_sends/create_a_triggered_send/).

**Related documentation:**

- [Marketing Cloud Connect - Triggered Sends](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_connector_v5/sending_emails/triggered_sends/)
- [Marketing Cloud Connect - Create a Triggered Send](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_connector_v5/sending_emails/triggered_sends/create_a_triggered_send/)